# Как перевести «\n» в строку?

Tags: java

Как мне перевести `\n` в строку?
Если я пишу:

```
строка \n строка
```

После компиляции выдаст:

```
строка

строка
```

, но как мне записать `\n` таким образом, чтобы получить **строка \n строка** после компиляции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо написать две палки перед n, вместо одной: `\\n`.

Comment: а экранировать как в пайтоне r'\n' можно ?

Comment: Нет, так нельзя экранировать. Функцию экранирования в яве выполняет симол `\\`, которые делает специальные символы обычными, например \ - специальный символ, а \\ в процессе компиляции превращается в \, также с кавычками и символом '.